# how to navigate in spark list control?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, flex4.5

I'm building a mobile app, using spark list control. When user tap on a list item, i want it to navigate to that correspondence page

```
<s:List id="list" width="100%" height="100%" labelField=" label">
<s:dataProvider>
<s:ArrayList>
<fx:Object label="Page One" />
<fx:Object label="Page Two" />
<fx:Object label="Page Three" />
<fx:Object label="Page Four" />
</s:ArrayList>
</s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

how do i code it so that when user tap on item label="Page One" it will navigate to PageOneView.mxml and if it tap on "Page Two" it will go to PageTwoView.mxml and so on.
 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The List should dispatch a change event.  In that change event handler you can push the new view onto the view stack:

```
if(list.selectedIndex == 0){
 navigator.pushView(viewOne);
} else if (list.selectedIndex == 1){
 navigator.pushView(viewtwo);
} else if 
etc...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, could it be better if i use **loop** instead of **If...else**?

Comment: @jameslcs I'm not sure how you would use a loop, but it depends on your data structure.  It'd be better if the objects in your dataProvider had a reference to the view or view class you wanted them to instantiate when clicked.

Comment: i was thinking of getting the arraylist length and loop through it eg. PageView01 = index 0, PageView02 = index 1, and so on. then i don't need to use a lot of else if, when those pages started to add up.

Comment: @jameslcs Couldn't you just create the view name dynamically using the selectedIndex property?  I'm still thinking a loop is not a good approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I like the switch statement here as you can default to an action,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="HomeView">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
            {
                switch(list.selectedItem.label)
                {
                    case "Page One":
                    {
                        navigator.pushView(pageOne);
                        break;
                    }
                    case "Page Two":
                    {
                        navigator.pushView(pageTwo);
                        break;
                    }                   
                    case "Page Three":
                    {
                        navigator.pushView(pageThree);
                        break;
                    }                   
                    case "Page Four":
                    {
                        navigator.pushView(pageFour);
                        break;
                    }                       
                    default:
                    {
                        navigator.pushView(pageOne);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:List id="list" width="100%" height="100%" change="list_changeHandler(event)"
            labelField="label">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object label="Page One"/>
                <fx:Object label="Page Two"/>
                <fx:Object label="Page Three"/>
                <fx:Object label="Page Four"/>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>
</s:View>
```

Just a different way, suits my logic, created in Flash Builder 4.6.

Jacko