# How to create a list of Views in Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: android, listview, mobile, calculator, flash-builder

I am currently writing an android Application in Flash builder. Ultimately I would like to create a suite of calculators within Flash builder. I would like the main screen to be a long list of calculators. The user will have the ability to search the name of the calculator they want, and have the name of calculators returned to them. I do not know where to start to implement this type of an application.

Please help. I will provide a picture of the application, to show what I am looking for. The gray box underneath the go and search bar is where I would like to add my list of calculators. If you look in the left of the screen you will see A1C Calculator where I have already began to work on the first one.

Thank you for your time.

Ryan, 
P.S. They made me take the image off since i am a new user, if you would like to see the image please send me an email or message. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Update. Greetings I have found the source to this answer. if anyone else is looking for an answer like this one go to this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153068/how-to-navigate-in-spark-list-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have learned with this approach is that each page must have an assigned ID. Once you have implemented this in the code, the ArrayList is what is defined next. The Array List should also have an ID. Notice below the Data provider for this specific application component is the ArrayList.

```
<s:List id="list" width="100%" height="100%" labelField=" label">
    <s:dataProvider>
    <s:ArrayList>
    <fx:Object label="Page One" />
    <fx:Object label="Page Two" />
    <fx:Object label="Page Three" />
    <fx:Object label="Page Four" />
    </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```